# Getting ‘m_Mutex’ declared as reference but not initialized error

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, mutex

I am trying to implement Mutex lock on one of my static function of single ton class. But getting this error:

```
$error:‘m_Mutex’ declared as reference but not initialized
$warning:warning: unused variable ‘m_Mutex’
```

Here is my code snippet.

========Commondefines.h==========

```
/**
*@class LockBlock
*This class is used to provide Mutex Lock on thread.
*/
class LockBlock
{
    public:
        LockBlock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
        {
            lockMutex = mutex;
            pthread_mutex_lock(lockMutex);
        };


        ~LockBlock()
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(lockMutex);
            lockMutex = NULL;
        }


    private:
        pthread_mutex_t *lockMutex;
};
```

========MutexImplenation.h======

```
#include "CommonDefines.h"

class MutexImplementation
{

  private:
     static pthread_mutex_t m_Mutex ;

  public:
     static void commonFunction();

};
```

====MutexImplementation.cpp==========

```
// Initialize static member of class.
pthread_mutex_t MutexImplentation::m_Mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


void commonFunction()
{
   LockBlock(&m_Mutex); // Here I am getting this error.


}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Yuvi

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is really a variant of the "most embarassing parse" problem.
You've not defined a `m_Mutex` anywhere except as a member of
`MutexImplementation`, so outside of `MutexImplementation`, its name is
`MutexImplementation::m_Mutex` (and since it's private, you can't
legally access it).  When you write:

```
LockBlock (&m_Mutex);
```

, the compiler cannot find `m_Mutex`, and so supposes that you are
defining a local variable.  The parentheses are legal, but have no
effect, and the declaration is the same as:

```
LockBlock& m_Mutex;
```

A reference to `LockBlock`, and references can only be defined if they
are initialized.

If you want a local variable, you'll have to give it a name.  And if you
want it initialized to `m_Mutex`, you'll have to make `m_Mutex` public,
and specify the class name as well:

```
LockBlock& localRefToMutex( &MutexImplementation::m_Mutex );
```

for example.

Comment: when I use `LockBlock& localRefToMutex( &MutexImplementation::m_Mutex );` M getting  `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘LockBlock&’ from a temporary of type ‘pthread_mutex_t*’` but when I use `LockBlock localRefToMutex( &MutexImplementation::m_Mutex );` it is being properly compiled.

Comment: I didn't look beyond syntax in making the correction.  Semantics count as well: what is `localRefToMutex` supposed to refer to?  The expression `&MutexImplementation::m_Mutex` doesn't have type `LockBlock`, and even if it did, it isn't an lvalue, so it can't be used to initialize a reference to a `LockBlock`.